# How to query for items that were moved from current iteration to a different iteration?

Tags: tfs, iteration

I am trying to query items(Features, User-Stories, Tasks) that were moved from current iteration to a different iteration (like next iteration),  for our team to see which items we didn't accomplished in the current iteration.

Is there a way to do this in TFS?

My TFS Version is 2017 Update 3 RTM

Comment: You could use a query with `And | Iteration Path | Was Ever | Your original iteration`

Comment: Not good. I don't have 'Was Ever' option for Iteration Path. Only: Under, Not Under, =, <>, In.

Answer (score 0):

You can track the progress of requirements, bugs, and other work to be completed in the current sprint using the **@CurrentIteration** macro.

Any item assigned to a sprint which corresponds to the current iteration path for the team will be found. For example, if a team is on Sprint 5, then the query will return items assigned to Sprint 5. Later, when the team is working in Sprint 6, the same query will return items assigned to Sprint 6.

> **Note**
>
> For the @CurrentIteration macro to work, the team must have selected
>   an Iteration Path whose date range encompasses the current date. For
>   details, see [Define iteration paths (aka sprints) and configure team
>   iterations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-iteration-paths-sprints?view=azure-devops#activate). Also, queries that contain this macro are only valid
>   when run from the web portal.
>
> See also [Client restrictions on the use of the @CurrentIteration
>   macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-by-date-or-current-iteration?view=azure-devops#client-restrictions-on-the-use-of-the--macros) later in this article.

After exclude those current iteration items, you should be easy to determine those items you need and then you can check the history of these work items which the previous iteration path they are.

Comment: Your suggestion works, but I don't want to do manual work. Of course I can check manually for example after I query for \@CurrentIteration +1 and then check the history of each item. But it's a lot of work and I wonder if there is a way to get exactly all the items that were in \@CurrentIteration and now they are in \@CurrentIteration +1

Comment: @Davis8988 Thanks for your detail explanation. It's not able to do this through a single query at present. Sorry for any inconvenience. You could  raise a feature request https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/visual-studio-team-services.html?type=idea Our PM will kindly review your suggestion. The simple solution is just as comment suggested adding a "was ever " condition for Iteration Path field.

Answer (score 0):

One tip is to have a habit of tagging work items with sprint name eg. "P27" from which they were moved to an other sprint. Then it is easy to query. Even though this requires some manual routine tagging ...

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to do this using the WIQL query method described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-by-date-or-current-iteration?view=azure-devops#list-work-items-moved-out-of-a-sprint

Using this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.wiql-editor

I did not get the WIQL extension to work though.... clicking "Save Query" lead to no changes

Example of a WIQL query that should work:

```
SELECT
    [System.Id],
    [System.WorkItemType],
    [System.AssignedTo],
    [System.Title],
    [System.State],
    [System.Tags],
    [System.IterationPath],
    [System.AreaPath]
FROM workitems
WHERE
    [System.TeamProject] = @project
    AND [System.WorkItemType] IN ('User Story', 'Bug')
    AND [System.AreaPath] UNDER 'FabrikamFiber\Web'
    AND NOT [System.State] IN ('Completed', 'Closed', 'Cut', 'Resolved')
    AND NOT [System.IterationPath] = @currentIteration('[FabrikamFiber]\Web <id:cdf5e823-1179-4503-9fb1-a45e2c1bc6d4>')
    AND (
        EVER (
            [System.IterationPath] = @currentIteration('[FabrikamFiber]\Web <id:cdf5e823-1179-4503-9fb1-a45e2c1bc6d4>')
        )
        AND [System.IterationPath] = @currentIteration('[FabrikamFiber]\Web <id:cdf5e823-1179-4503-9fb1-a45e2c1bc6d4>') + 1
        AND [System.ChangedDate] >= @today - 30
    )
ORDER BY [System.Id]
```